# Multiple line strings in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a very long string that must be broken into multiple lines. How can I do that in zeppelin?

[image]

The error is `error: missing argument list for method + in class String`:

Here is the more complete error message:

```
<console>:14: error: missing argument list for method + in class String
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `$plus _` or `$plus(_)` instead of `$plus`.
         val q = "select count(distinct productId),count(distinct date),count(distinct instock_inStockPercent), count(distinct instock_totalOnHand)," +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala (using Apache Zeppelin as well as otherwise), you can write expressions covering multiple lines by wrapping them in parentheses:

```
val text = ("line 1"
      + "line 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using parentheses

As Theus mentioned. One way is parentheses.

```
val text = ("line 1" + 
    "line 2")
```

Actually all multiline statements which break by semantics can be included by parentheses. like.

```
(object.function1()
.function2())
```

### Using `"""`

For multiline string. We can use `"""`, like this,

```
val s = """line 1
           line2
           line3"""
```

The leading space before `line2` and `line3` will be included. If we don't want to to have the leading spaces. We can use like this.

```
val s = """line 1
          |line2
          |line3""".stripMargin
```

Or using different strip character

```
val s = """line 1
          $line2
          $line3""".stripMargin('$')
```